# How to validate id_token received by asp.net mvc OWIN from azure AD B2C

Tags: c#, azure, owin

We have a security requirement that we must validate the id token we receive from Azure AD B2C. We need to validate these at the minimum

**customSecurityLevel**, **audience**, **not before and "expiration time",  issuer, nonce**

Looking asp.net MVC OWIN middleware, I noticed that that OpenIdConnectAuthenicationOptions provides these:

```
return new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ...
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications //Specifies events which the OpenIdConnectAuthenticationMiddleware invokes to enable developer control over the authentication process.
                {
                    AuthenticationFailed = this.AuthenticationFailed,
                    RedirectToIdentityProvider = this.RedirectToIdentityProvider,
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = this.OnAuthorizationCodeReceived,
                },

                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    SaveSigninToken = true,           // Important to save the token in boostrapcontext
                    ValidateAudience = true,          // Validate the Audience
                    ValidateIssuer = true,            // Validate the Issuer
                    ValidateLifetime = true,          // Validate the tokens lifetime
                    ValidIssuer = Issuer,             // The issuer to be validated
                    ValidAudience = ClientId,          // The Audience to be validated
                },
            };
```

Being quiet new to OWIN, I'm trying to understand below:

1. Does OWIN middleware magically validates the token we receive from Azure AD B2C  or do we need to manually perform validation per this:
   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-manual-jwt-validation/
2. At what point in time should token validation should occur i.e. AuthorizationCodeReceived event or on redirect controller/action (page) that's configured on Azure AD B2C redirect URL?
3. We need to validate more attributes that TokenValidationParameters supports e.g. customSecurityAttribute we send on initial payload. Is there a way to extend this?

   4. How do we parse the token that we receive from Azure AD B2C using OWIN?

Any code sample would be handy.

Answer (score 1):

TO make your question simpler.

The idea behind token is to parse the token and get 3 parts from the token

```
-Header : contain information about in which algorithm the token haven been encrypted

-Payload : information about the user

-Signature: it's the calculation of encryption of ( Header + Payload) using the Azure certificate or( your identity provider).
```

Next step the user sends request to your back-end along with JWT.

your back-end will parse the token and get certificate type then will preform HTTP request to your identity provider to get certificate

Next your back-end will construct the certificate option and try to do encryption for ( header  + Payload) came from your token the output string must be exactly same Signature you received in the token from your front-end.

If every thing is okay 
now your back-end will start validating other attributes like Audience, Issuer
if you configure your token to validate the Audience means your front-end required to provide token contain Audience(Application ID) exactly same your back-end as well as for issuer.

the question now how my back-end knows about certificate?
Azure AD using OpenID connect, [More information here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code)
since you configred you tenant in backend the auth packge will make a call to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/.well-known/openid-configuration` to get the details about your identity provider
and one important link as will is `("jwks_uri": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/discovery/keys")` where the signature hosted.
You can read and search more how to validate certificate JWT and check this
`https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70005/authentication-with-jwt`

moving to part 2 of validate more attributes.
Since you are using OpenIdConnect, the package has class called `OpenIdConnectEvents` that you can trigger events and do what ever you want like this

```
.AddOpenIdConnect(o =>
    {
        //Additional config snipped
        o.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async ctx =>
            {
                //Get user's immutable object id from claims that came from Azure AD
                string oid = ctx.Principal.FindFirstValue("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier");

                //Get EF context
                var db = ctx.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<AuthorizationDbContext>();

                //Check is user a super admin
                bool isSuperAdmin = await db.SuperAdmins.AnyAsync(a => a.ObjectId == oid);
                if (isSuperAdmin)
                {
                    //Add claim if they are
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "superadmin")
                    };
                    var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);

                    ctx.Principal.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                }
            }
        };
});
```

moving to part 3 
parsing token in javascript

```
function parseJwt (token) {
            var base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
            var base64 = base64Url.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/');
            return JSON.parse(window.atob(base64));
};
```

parsing token in C#

use this libary https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/

```
try {
  string jsonPayload = JWT.JsonWebToken.Decode(token, secretKey);
  Console.WriteLine(jsonPayload);
} catch (JWT.SignatureVerificationException) {
  Console.WriteLine("Invalid token!");
}
```

or manual

```
var jwtHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
var jwtInput = txtJwtIn.Text;

//Check if readable token (string is in a JWT format)
var readableToken = jwtHandler.CanReadToken(jwtInput);

if(readableToken != true)
{
  txtJwtOut.Text = "The token doesn't seem to be in a proper JWT format.";
}
if(readableToken == true)
{
  var token = jwtHandler.ReadJwtToken(jwtInput);

  //Extract the headers of the JWT
  var headers = token.Header;
  var jwtHeader = "{";
  foreach(var h in headers)
  {
    jwtHeader += '"' + h.Key + "\":\"" + h.Value + "\",";
  }
  jwtHeader += "}";
  txtJwtOut.Text = "Header:\r\n" + JToken.Parse(jwtHeader).ToString(Formatting.Indented);

  //Extract the payload of the JWT
  var claims = token.Claims;
  var jwtPayload = "{";
  foreach(Claim c in claims)
  {
    jwtPayload += '"' + c.Type + "\":\"" + c.Value + "\",";
  }
  jwtPayload += "}";
  txtJwtOut.Text += "\r\nPayload:\r\n" + JToken.Parse(jwtPayload).ToString(Formatting.Indented);  
}
```

I hope that answer your qustions

Comment: Thanks Khaled. I've few more questions.
To set context, we need to validate the token we receive after calling b2c Authorize end point.

1.  Noticed that Owin provides "SecurityTokenValidated", does it mean it performs validation out of box or do we need to manually validate?

2. At what point in time should we validate the token we received from Azure AD B2C.

Comment: Hi, Yes `Microsoft.IdentityModel` doing the validation out of the box and insure that you are protected. it's highly recommended from Microsoft that you don't do validate token manual leave `Microsoft.IdentityModel` to do it for you.

Comment: what you can do if you have more requirement example `check if user banded from the system` you have the option using `OpenIdConnectEvents` to reject the request to inform `IdentityModel` that the user should not continue and you need to stop his request immediately and that's why you have `OnTokenValidated `, You can do test by send change in the token any value and send to your back-end , the response code status should be (401) means unauthorized.

Comment: Is OpenIdConnectEvents  and OnTokenValidated  part of asp.net core? I'm using asp.net MVC instead.

Comment: Also, does OWIN provides strongly typed claims with custom properties e.g. mobile,  address etc that's configured in azure b2c? If not, how do we get and parse this claim details?